# How to filter out unwanted data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, exists

So currently my results include $0.1 and $0.1 amount for some customers but I would like to filter out these results  to only include results that has $2 and $2 etc.
My current query looks like this but I am unable to filter out the unwanted data

```
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT TransBalance, AccBalance
  FROM @combined
  WHERE TransBalance between '0.10' and '-0.10'
    AND AccBalance between '0.10' and '-0.10'
)
```

I am using `TSQL`

Comment: add your complete query.

Comment: The exists clause has no correlation and it is hard to guess what you are trying to do,add  sample output

Comment: `BETWEEN` expects that first parameter is less than the second parameter. Also, specifying dollar amounts as strings is not a good idea. It should be `BETWEEN -0.10 AND 0.10`. It is even better to not use `BETWEEN` at all: `Balance >= -0.10 AND Balance <= 0.10`.